# Elasticsearch index with no fields indexed

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to create an Elasticsearch index whose contents will be accessed only by the document-id. There will never be any queries related to the contents of documents. These documents can contain *any* JSON, including instances where the same field can contain different types of data, etc.

I've hunted for this info, and have found much about indexing individual fields, but nothing about treating the entire document as essentially opaque.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: To make a field unsearchable (and thus not indexed), I think it is possible to use the `index : false` option of a mapping (see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.4/mapping-index.html). Then it might be possible to use the default mapping so that all fields from the index have the option `index : false` (see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.4/default-mapping.html). (that's a lot of maybe, but it's hard to do more with so little information)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that you want, but as for me, this is not right way.

For first you need to create a mapping for index:

```
PUT index_name_here
{
    "mappings": {
        "document_type_here": {
            "properties": {
                "field_name_for_json_data_here": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "enabled": false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After this, you could create documents with custom structure of fields. You just need to store you JSON not directly in document, but inside field of document (in my example inside field "field_name_for_json_data_here")

If it possible, tell me the reason, why you choose Elasticsearch for store this kind of data? Because if I correctly understood the question, you need simple key\value storage (you could store you json as string) and many databases are more suitable for this.

Comment: This use case could definitely be implemented in a much simpler database, but we have many other indexes that are using Elasticsearch to its fullest.